# Question about set in java, how does Set works to distinct the duplicate elements?

Tags: java, arrays, list, set, hashset

Can anyone please explain to me how Set works in java? Code as following:

---

```
             List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
             list.add(1);
             list.add(2);
             list.add(3);
             List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
             list1.add(1);
             list1.add(2);
             list1.add(3);
             Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
             set.add(list);
             set.add(list1);
             System.out.println(set);

             int[] arr = new int[3];
             arr[0] = 1;
             arr[1] = 2;
             arr[2] = 3;
             int[] arr1 = new int[3];
             arr1[0] = 1;
             arr1[1] = 2;
             arr1[2] = 3;
             Set<int[]> set1 = new HashSet<>();
             set1.add(arr);
             set1.add(arr1);
             System.out.println(set1);
```

---

output:
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[I@7852e922, [I@6d06d69c]

My question is how does Set can distinct ArrayList/List? But cannot distinct array? I thought both are pass by reference and both are the object right?

Comment: The difference is in how they define hashCode and equals.

Comment: To add to that comment, arrays in Java don't override `Object.hashCode` and `Object.equals` and therefore only consider the exact same array instance to be equal to itself.

Comment: To say it pithily: A and B can be distinguished iff `!A.equals(B)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new object to a `set<SomeClass>`, it calls `equals()` method on `SomeClass` class. If it returns false (i.e same value doesn't exist), it adds the object to the set.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

```
// equals() method of AbstractList class is called here because the set is // of List type

Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
             set.add(list);
             set.add(list1); //list.equals(list1) is true at this point
// This is the reason you got unique values

---------------
// whereas when you add a plain array which is just a plain java object, equals() // gets called on Object class which compares by reference
// This is the reason you don't get unique values

Set<int[]> set1 = new HashSet<>();
             set1.add(arr);
             set1.add(arr1);
```

Furthermore, in case of `Set<Employee>` where employee is a user defined class. If we don't define equals() method with custom rules in Employee class, inherited `equals()` method from `Object` class will be called and the set will not have unique values.